# strange html rendering on android with google chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

This very simple html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph with some text. Paragraph with some text. Paragraph
        with some text. Paragraph with some text. Paragraph with some text.</p>
    Label: <input type="text"> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Button">
    <p>Paragraph with some text. Paragraph with some text. Paragraph
        with some text. Paragraph with some text. Paragraph with some text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

is displayed in google chrome on android 4.1.2 with very small font size for the "Label:" and the input field.

How can I make the label and the paragraph have the same font size?

Even when I specify a *style="font-size: 24px"* for all parts (the label and input wrapped with a "p") the label and input still appear with a much smaller font size. You can test it here: [link to the above html](http://www.quadripedia.de/andrchrometest.html)

[image: screenshot]

P.S. putting less text in the two "p"s makes it work properly.

Comment: this content is currently not wrapped in a `p` or so, so it's probably taking a style from a parent (body ?) or the default style. What happens when you actually wrap them into a `p`tag ? Also, it might help to inspect your code and identify the applied CSS to those elements... the answer is most probably there.

Comment: I don't know why, but doubling the font size on the 'faulty' elements seemed to fix it. Not a clean solution however. EDIT: http://i.imgur.com/nhU3Ybg.png

Comment: Wrapping in a p doesn't change it. There is no css involved. - What do you mean by "doubling font size"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```